# Is it possible to restrict picklist values for a lightning-input-field?

Tags: lightning-web-components, create-records, lightning-inputfield

Currently, it seems that there is no way to remove some of the options for a picklist while using the [lightning-input-field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field) (in my case on the [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation)).

The only solution I came up with is to use the lightning-combobox instead. However, with this implementation, a custom creation of the record has to be developed which defeats the whole purpose of using the lighting form.

Answer (score 1):

The way to still use lightning record edit forms and custom combobox field is overriding the save behaviour of form.

```
 <lightning-record-edit-form
        object-api-name="ObjectApiName"
        onsubmit={handleSuccess}
    >
 other lighning input field
  .......
 combobox field
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Now in js, you can override the values in form

```
handleSubmit(event){
   event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
   const fields = event.detail.fields;
   fields.picklistfieldapiname__c = 'some value';
   this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
}
```